# Python3 on Windows IIS server. Need unbuffered output live output

Tags: python, python-3.x, iis, cgi

This is the code I have below I am not able to get the output to be live and the browser must wait. I have read the compression stuff and this works with Perl using $|=1 on the same server

```
#!"C:\Python37\python.exe" -u
import time
import sys


print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n")
print ("<HTML>")

for i in range (30):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print ('!')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below codes to disable buffer with python print function.

```
class Unbuffered(object):
   def __init__(self, stream):
       self.stream = stream
   def write(self, data):
       self.stream.write(data)
       self.stream.flush()
   def writelines(self, datas):
       self.stream.writelines(datas)
       self.stream.flush()
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       return getattr(self.stream, attr)

import sys
sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
print {Hello}
```

Then I suggest you could follow below answer to disable this output buffering in IIS.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28964536/Disable-output-buffering-in-IIS8-for-CGI-exe-file-output.html